# Would a device demanding too many amps, damage a battery?

Tags: batteries, amperage

Would a device demanding too many amps(I mean more than a battery is rated for), damage a rechargeable battery?

e.g. let's say a rechargeable battery is rated at 2A and a device demands 2.5A or 3A or more.

Would it damage the battery?

Comment: Indeed, think about it, **WHY** would the battery have a rating ??? If it was safe for a 2 A battery to deliver 3 A then wouldn't it rated at 3 A ?

Comment: @FakeMoustache you have to have a knowledge in electronics to know that. Answers based on knowledge, such as those given, are better than cautious intuitions based on ignorance. For example, while , as answers describe, it clearly it would damage the battery, in contrast, if a battery were rated at 10A and a device was rated at 5A, then the battery won't damage the device, even though the ratings are different, 'cos an electronics knowledge tells us that the device uses what it needs.  So decisions on these matters should be based on knowledge rather than cautious or hazardous guessing games.

Comment: @FakeMoustache plus anyhow, the answers have addressed my question well.

Comment: First make sure you know the difference between a 2A rating and a 2Ah rating.

Comment: @BrianDrummond yeah not asking about amp hours.. I am not asking about how long the battery can last.. it could just be any ACDC adaptor that i'm talking about rather than necessarily a battery. So, indeed, Amps.

Answer (score 2):

Potentially, yes.

The more current a battery puts out, the more heat is dissipated in the internal resistance of the battery. As soon as the battery starts to exceed its rated temperature, this will cause problems. Li-ion batteries can catch fire if short-circuited.

(The exact behaviour depends on the battery chemistry; some of the more exotic ones like molten salt won't have this problem.)

Answer (score 1):

The time/current relation should be stated in the datasheet. If it isn't you must assume that no overcurrent is allowed.

If you use your battery outside the specifications all kinds of things can happen, ranging from "works fine for me" to "my house is on fire now".

Answer (score 1):

*Think* about it.  You are asking if violating a spec can cause damage.

Of course it can.

That's why batteries come with specs.  They tell you what the battery can do if operated properly, and define what proper operation is.  Whenever you violate any proper operation requirement of a device, all remaining promises about what it will do and not do are null and void.

If you short a battery, most likely the current will exceed the maximum spec, and you will quite likely damage the battery.

Again, *think* about it.  How else can this possibly work?